# Need Help on Android google map's

Tags: android, google-maps

I dropped a pin on Google map, if I click that pin means, it shows the place information. This is working fine. But , My requirement is , when clicked that pin , i want to go some particular page, which is included in my code.
For ex: If i click this pin, i want to go the information details page in the application. How can I add the click event for the Google map point.
Here is my sample snippet..

```
private MapView mapView;

mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map_view);
mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
mapView.setTraffic(true);

List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(12.826782 * 1e6),(int)(80.220298 * 1e6));
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hello", "Helloo World!");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

MapController mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.animateTo(point);
mapController.setZoom(3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CustomItemizedOverlay, you need to overide ItemizedOverlay.onTap(int).

You'll have something like that :

```
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  // Do something with the item
  return true;
}
```

When this action occurs, if you want to create an activity, you'll need to have the Context or to notify a listener. From my point of view, the second solution is better :

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

    private MapItemListener mMapItemListener;

    ...

    public void setMapItemListener(MapItemListener mapItemListener) {
        this.mMapItemListener = mapItemListener;
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);

      if (mMapItemListener != null){
        mMapItemListener.onMapItemTap(item);
      }

      return true;
    }

    public interface MapItemListener {
            void onMapItemTap(OverlayItem item);
    }
}
```

And in your activity :

```
public class MyMapActivity extends MapActivity implements MapItemListener {


    protected void myInitMapMethod(){
        ...
        CustomItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);
        itemizedOverlay.setMapItemListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapItemTap(OverlayItem item) {
        // Start activity
    }

}
```